# How to add LIKE parameter in mongodb geoNear command

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I am searching

db.runCommand({
    geoNear: "users",
    near:[56,11],
    maxDistance:100/6387,
    distanceMultiplier:6387,
    query:  { "city": /^bos/}
})

So here i am trying to get results with distances(priority) & city name that starts with bos

as we make LIKE query call in mysql so 
i am not able to get results.

Please tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the "query" parameter to the command should give you the results that you are looking for.

One possible reason that your query might not be working is that regular expressions are case-sensitive unless specified as case-insensitive with the 'i' flag.

For example:

```
> db.places.save({_id:1, city:"CityA", loc:[56.01,11.01]})
> db.places.save({_id:2, city:"CityB", loc:[56.02,11.02]})
> db.places.ensureIndex({loc:"2d"})
> db.runCommand({ geoNear: "places", near:[56,11], maxDistance:1, distanceMultiplier:1, query: { "city": /^city/} })
{
    "ns" : "test.places",
    "near" : "1100100000111111111100110000110000111111111100110000",
    "results" : [ ],
    "stats" : {
        "time" : 0,
        "btreelocs" : 0,
        "nscanned" : 2,
        "objectsLoaded" : 2,
        "avgDistance" : NaN,
        "maxDistance" : 0
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Nothing is returned.  Now the command is rerun, with the case-insensitive flag in the regex part of the query:

```
> db.runCommand({ geoNear: "places", near:[56,11], maxDistance:1, distanceMultiplier:1, query: { "city": /^city/i} })
{
    "ns" : "test.places",
    "near" : "1100100000111111111100110000110000111111111100110000",
    "results" : [
        {
            "dis" : 0.014142135623729393,
            "obj" : {
                "_id" : 1,
                "city" : "CityA",
                "loc" : [
                    56.01,
                    11.01
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "dis" : 0.02828427124746381,
            "obj" : {
                "_id" : 2,
                "city" : "CityB",
                "loc" : [
                    56.02,
                    11.02
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "stats" : {
        "time" : 0,
        "btreelocs" : 0,
        "nscanned" : 2,
        "objectsLoaded" : 2,
        "avgDistance" : 0.0212132034355966,
        "maxDistance" : 0.028292673810819097
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
>
```

Both locations are returned.  The documentation on using regular expression with Mongo queries may be found in the "Regular Expressions" section of the "Advanced Queries" page:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions

Hopefully the above will resolve your issue and allow you to perform the correct query.